# Creating nested suites in scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I need to be able executing the following command in sbt: *sbt myproject/it:test*
but to make sure that only

```
class Combiner extends Suites(new TestSuite1,new TestSuite2,new TestSuite3)
```

will be executed instead of Combiner + TestSuite1 + TestSuite2 + TestSuite3 all being executed.
Now I'm aware of the fact that I can provide a specific class to execute in sbt  - this is not what I want since I do not want other team members to remember running special sbt commands in one specific project.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently if you use the @DoNotDiscover annotation on the individual   suites (TestSuite1,TestSuite2 etc..) they are not discovered automatically by the framework
but if they're explicitly mentioned  as part of the "Combiner",
then they are being discovered.